# AddTodo method in service not working when called from component

Tags: angular, rxjs, behaviorsubject

I have a todo application that is using the Subject as a Service approach to state management.

My todo service looks like this

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Todo } from './todo.model';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject, map, pipe } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class TodosService {
  private todos$ = new BehaviorSubject<Todo[]>([]);
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.http
      .get<Todo[]>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1/todos')
      .subscribe((todos) => {
        this.todos$.next(todos);
      });
  }

  public getTodos(): Observable<Todo[]> {
    return this.todos$;
  }

  public getCompletedTodos(): Observable<Todo[]> {
    return this.todos$.pipe(
      map((todos) => todos.filter((todo) => todo.completed))
    );
  }

  public addTodo(event: string) {
    const newArray: Todo[] = [
      ...this.todos$.value,
      {
        userId: 1,
        id: this.todos$.value.length,
        title: event,
        completed: false,
      },
    ];
    this.todos$.next(newArray);
  }
}
```

And my add-todo component looks likes this.

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { TodosService } from './todo.service';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-todo',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule],
  providers: [TodosService],
  template: `
    <label>Add Todo</label>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="todo" />
    <button (click)="addNewTodo()">Submit</button>
  `,
})
export class AddTodo {
  todo: string = '';
  constructor(private todoService: TodosService) {}

  addNewTodo() {
    this.todoService.addTodo(this.todo);
    this.todo = '';
  }

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

I know that my addTodo method is being called by the component because I can console log the newArray value and see it when I try to add a new one. But for some reason my new todo isn't being displayed.

What's weirder is that this works fine when I call addTodo inside the constructor of my service. When done this way, my component that displays the todos updates properly.

```
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.http
      .get<Todo[]>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1/todos')
      .subscribe((todos) => {
        this.todos$.next(todos);
      });

      setTimeout(()=> {
        this.addTodo('Todo from inside setTimeout')
      }, 3000)
  }
```

[image: Todo App]

So why does my list-todo component not update when addTodo is called from a component, rather than inside the service itself?

I've created a [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uxxjja?file=src/todo.service.ts)

Comment: your problem is that you are providing the `TodosService` at the component level, so each component is using a different instance of the service.  You need to provide the service at the app level so both components use the same instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by @BizzyBob in the comments, if you provide `TodosService` on component-level, each component will get their own instance of a `TodosService` and there will be no shared states between them.

In your case you can solve this by providing `TodosService` inside your `App` component in your `main.ts` and removing the individual provider arrays from your standalone components.

Your `App` component will look like:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    TodoList,
    TodoListSubscribe,
    HttpClientModule,
    AddTodo,
  ],
  providers: [TodosService],
  template: `
    <app-todo-list></app-todo-list>
    <app-add-todo></app-add-todo>
  `,
})
export class App {}
```

Comment: that's a great answer, and I wonder what can I do if I don't want this service to be available over the entire application but still want to use the same instance in a few components?!

Comment: inject the service at root level

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative to @tomcek112 solution is to mark your service as `providedIn: 'root` using its decorator, this way angular will instanciate the service once at the root level, and reuse that same instance application wide.

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TodosService {
    /* service code */
}
```